# Get Gingerbread back on Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: downgrade, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y mobile. In internet I saw a post that update your Samsung Galaxy Y from 2.3 to 4.0. I tried the steps but I went wrong now my mobile getting rebooted again and again. How can I get my previous version?

Comment: Restore the nanddroid backup you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. I got the Solution [here](http://www.latesthub.org/how-to-flash-galaxy-y-original-stock-rom/8112)

Answer (score 3):

If you can enter into Recovery Mode(with Power and Volume Up buttons pressed on startup) try to restore a nandroid backup(if made) or flash a new ROM.

If you can't enter into Recovery Mode you need to reflash a stock ROM using ODIN. You need to choose the Right Stock ROM for your region. See [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1465800), it also contains a guide to flash these files with ODIN.

Then you can go on trying to update to ICS or JB.